Using .pdf files of Copyrighted Works That Are Freely Available Online
I am a high school student and passionate about pure math.
I was able to procure my collection of pure mathematics books by purchasing them at a discount price at garage sales, bookstores, book sales, etc. However, with my limited budget, I cannot afford to buy all the books I want to read or need to reference.
If I were to use pdf versions that are freely circulated on the internet, would this be legal?
My initial assumption would be that it is legal for a few reasons: an appeal case that allows Georgia State University to publish large portions of copyrighted documents; the fact that I would only be using this copyrighted material to further my education, and would not be distributing the copyrighted material; I have exhausted all personal options that would allow me to purchase the book, thus not permitting the publisher any money either way; The work that I would be using would be completely nonfictional and factual.
In addition to this I have also looked through the fair use index, and have found little in the way of cases pertaining directly to me, but have found the case Cambridge University Press v. Mark P. Becker. This to me raised the question of is it only illegal to distribute the copyrighted material, and legal to look at it if someone else has already distributed it.
I would also bring up the fact that many of these .pdf files are available quite freely online and by prominent universities, some of these .pdf files even being displayed when just the name of the book is searched. These have files have been up for over a decade in some cases and for the most part a few years at the least. Does this imply a lack of caring on the publishers end and thus a loophole around the copyright issue.
Overall, I would like to ask whether it is at the very least legally ambiguous and would come down to the sympathies of the judge and or jury, though I do recognize that I would most likely never be tried in a case of personal use.

You go to your local college and use their public computers to download them with their subscription. If that isn’t an option you get your school library or public library to ILL. Otherwise you’re making an excuse.

"I would also bring up the fact that many of these .pdf files are available quite freely online and by prominent universities" - Yes, that sometimes happens. But that doesn't make it legal. It's likely that many profs posted such material on their university page, thinking they were making a copy available only to their students (even the legality of that is also questionable). But the mere fact that you found it on a university page doesn't mean it was done with permission by the publisher. Maybe, but likely not. Most likely the publisher just didn't complain (yet).

"I have exhausted all personal options that would allow me to purchase the book, thus not permitting the publisher any money either way" -- this excuse won't work. Just imagine using the same argument for going into a movie theatre: "well, I don't have enough to buy a ticket, and I can see that the theatre is not booked-up, therefore it should be legal that I just sneak in."

It might be legal
Prima facie, if you make a copy (by downloading a pdf to your browser for example) without permission, you are violating copyright law.
If the copyright owner discovers this (which they probably won’t) and chooses to sue you (which they have no obligation to do), you can raise a fair use (if in the USA) or fair dealing (if in any other English language jurisdiction) defence.
For fair use, each case is decided on its merits. So, it is impossible to know in advance if such a defence will succeed. The legal test is four factored and while you can make an assessment that your use is fair, ultimately the court makes the decision.
Fair dealing is more restrictive and more certain. The relevant copyright will clearly state what is and isn’t fair dealing. It varies by country but, typically for educational use, you are permitted to copy 10% or 1 chapter of a work.
You cannot read anything into the fact that the works are publicly posted. Perhaps the owner gave permission. Perhaps they are ok with universities using their work but not with others doing so. Perhaps they don’t know about it. Perhaps they don’t care. Perhaps they are hosted in a country that will not enforce copyright. Perhaps, perhaps, perhaps.
